# how to make image responsive css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a gif i am putting onto my screen, and it is not being resized properly. Here's the code:

```
  import broomAndText from './ezgif.com-video-to-gif-3.gif';
import './spinner.css';

function myGif() {

    return <html><body><div class="imgContainer"><img src={broomAndText} alt="broomAndText"/></div></body></html>
    
}

export default myGif;
```

then in my css, I have this:

```
.imgContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

on desktop it looks okay, please find the attached image below.
[image]

I took the SS at a bad time lol. and here's the second one, on mobile:
[image]

I'm not sure how to fix, this. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your image element inside a div that has height auto and width auto. That should autoscale your image :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. If you want it to scale you can always set `width: auto` and then set `max-height: to_whatever_you_want`

Comment: Like this for instance: https://jsfiddle.net/3Lu6jkt8/

Answer (score 0):

```
import broomAndText from './ezgif.com-video-to-gif-3.gif';
import './spinner.css';

function myGif() {
    return <html><body><div class="imgContainer"><img src={broomAndText} alt="broomAndText" width="100%" height="auto"/></div></body></html>
}

export default myGif;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for the mobile. It still gave the same result :(